# lights green field with a successful validation?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor

```
/* Styles for validation helpers
-----------------------------------------------------------*/
.field-validation-error {
    color: #ff0000;

}

.field-validation-valid {
    display: none;

}

.input-validation-error {

    background-color: #ffeeee;
     border:1px groove;
}

.validation-summary-errors {
    font-weight: bold;
    color: #ff0000;
}

.validation-summary-valid {
    display: none;
}
```

How lighted field in a green color with succesfull validation? Add new option ".input-validation-valid" dont help. May be used special jQuery plugins?  Thanks in advance for all your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you using query validation and unobtrusive validation, when a field is valid the error message is removed from the DOM so there's nothing to style! A typical error renders this (note the `<span>` within a `<span>`

```
<span class="field-validation-error" data-valmsg-for="Account.Description" data-valmsg-replace="true">
  <span for="Account_Description" generated="true" class="">Please enter a description</span>
</span>
```

When its valid, the inner span is removed and the class name changes to 'field-validation-valid'

```
<span class="field-validation-valid" data-valmsg-for="Account.Description" data-valmsg-replace="true"></span>
```